# Fuse cells in QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I'm working on a Qt project and I'm struck on a `QtDesign` issue.

I've at the moment a 4x4 grid, like that:

[image: Window layout]

- Top Left (TL): SourceSelector
- Top Right (TR): groupBox_vizualization
- Bottom Left (BL): groupBox_filtrage
- Bottom Right (BR): groupBox_spectre

I would like the `SourceSelector` to have a 100% width when I select one of the widgets in `stackWidget_source`. At the moment, when I select this widget I set the width of the "vizualisation" widget to 0, and hide it. I would like the `SourceSelector` to use 100% of the width in that case only. I order to have a grid (2)x(1 1).

But TL/BL et TR/BR always have the **same width**. So I can't make the TR one to use 100% as the BR has a fixed size.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved my problem with a Grid Layout at the bottom and a HLayout at the top. Both of them placed in a VLayout.